# WPF converting and binding checkbox value to visibility of UI element

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to create sample project for testing when checkbox is checked show textbox, otherwise hide it in WPF. So, i created following ViewModel:

```
    internal class TestViewModel
    {
        public bool IsCheckBoxChecked { get; set; }
    }
```

and *"boolean to visibility"* converter helper calss:

```
public class MyBoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool && (bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My XAML source:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWpfAppSample1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWpfAppSample1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chBox" Content="Is TextBox visible?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckBoxChecked}"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="63,98,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Test text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476" FontSize="14" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsCheckBoxChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and my XAML form source:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private TestViewModel viewModel;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new TestViewModel();
            chBox.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
```

but it is not working as i expected

[image]

Comment: Replace chBox.DataContext = viewModel with this.DataContext = viewModel.

Comment: It looks like condition in converter is reversed, please validate once

Comment: @mbshambharkar thank you for your solution, now my sample working right!

Comment: Also take a look at DataTriggers as an alternative to a Binding with Converter.